# The argument type 'ProductModel?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProductModel'

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, dart-null-safety

I'm making a midel to upload product image,price and name to firebase then i face this error (The argument type 'ProductModel?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProductModel'.)

```
    class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<ProductModel> pizzaProductList = [];
  ProductModel? productModel;

  fatchPizzaproductData() async {
   // List<ProductModel> newList = [];

    QuerySnapshot value =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("PizzaProducts").get();

     pizzaProductList = value.docs.map((element) {
      return ProductModel(
        productImage: element.get("productImage"),
        productName: element.get("productName"),
        productPrice: element.get("productPrice"),
      );
    }).toList();
    
  }

  get getPizzaproductDataList {
    return pizzaProductList;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `productModel` is a nullable type, whereas `pizzaProduct` is a List of *non-nullable* `ProductModel`s.

Instead of storing a property `productModel` on your class, consider mapping directly from `value.docs` to `pizzaProduct`, and removing the intermediate step of storing the model in `productModel`:

```dart
class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<ProductModel> pizzaProduct = [];

  Future<void> fetchPizzaProductData() async {
    QuerySnapshot value =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("PizzaProducts").get();

    pizzaProduct = value.docs.map((element) {
      return ProductModel(
        productImage: element.get("productImage"),
        productName: element.get("productName"),
        productPrice: element.get("productPrice"),
      );
    }).toList();

    // Since this is a ChangeNotifier, I'm assuming you might want to
    // notify listeners when `pizzaProduct` changes. Disregard this line
    // if that's not the case.
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: i updated the code can you check it again and correct it

Comment: The new code still has the same problem I pointed out, and I would still recommend the same solution :). Can you be more specific what about this solution is not working for you?

Comment: please tell me if i use your method productModel data store to  this list (  List<ProductModel> pizzaProduct = [];) ?

Comment: Ah I see - No, in my answer I'm saying you should get rid of `productModel`, as it's the reason you have an error. Instead, try mapping the values from `values.docs` and assign the resulting list to `pizzaProduct` as in the answer.

Comment: sorry i bother you i'm student and learming flutter,please check code again i think it is good now if you see any problem let me know thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It looks right, but you're the final judge :) - The question is, does it now do what you need it to do?